# Help converting Sentences to Logic and then creating clauses out of them

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

So here's the problem,

If the unicorn is mythical, then it is immortal, but if it is not mythical, then
it is a mortal mammal. If the unicorn is either immortal or a mammal,
then it is horned. The unicorn is magical if it is horned.

We want to convert the above sentences to logic using the following variables:

- MY = “Mythical Unicorn”
- IU = “Immortal Unicorn”
- MM = “Mortal Mammal”
- HU = “Horned Unicorn”
- MG = “Magical Unicorn”

So here's my attempt:

From the first half of the first sentence:
$$MY \implies IU$$
This then gets translated into:
$$ \neg MY \vee IU \tag{1}$$

Then from the second half of the first sentence:
$$\neg MY \implies MM $$
This then gets translated into:
$$MY \vee MM \tag{2}$$

From the third sentence:
$$(IU \vee MM) \implies HU$$
This then gets translated into:

$$ \neg (IU \vee MM) \vee HU $$

$$ = (\neg IU \wedge \neg MM) \vee HU$$

$$ (\neg IU \vee HU) \wedge (\neg MM \vee HU) \tag{3}$$ (Correct??)

The last one sentence above then gets translated into:
$$HU \implies MG$$
$$ = \neg HU \vee MG \tag{4}$$

Okay now the next part of the problem is I have to do is form clauses out of them.

So I'm guessing that I have to "and" all of my logical statements above together and then reduce them. Is that correct? My other guess would be to "and" together all of the logical statements from each english sentence together.

I'm gonna go with my first guess and say we should "and" them all together.

So, $$(1) \wedge (2) \wedge (3) \wedge (4)$$
$$ = \left[ \neg MY \vee IU \right] \wedge \left[ MY \vee MM  \right] \wedge \left[ (\neg IU \vee HU) \wedge (\neg MM \vee HU) \right] \wedge \left[  \neg HU \vee MG \right]$$

Okay... now looking at just the first two clauses, we see that they only way to satisfy both of them is for both $IU \text{and} MM$ to be true. Therefore, the logical sentence becomes

$$ = \left[ IU \wedge MM \right] \wedge \left[ (\neg IU \vee HU) \wedge (\neg MM \vee HU) \right] \wedge \left[  \neg HU \vee MG \right]$$

Looking at the center piece now,
$$\left[ (\neg IU \vee HU) \wedge (\neg MM \vee HU) \right]  = \left[ HU \vee [\neg IU \wedge \neg MM ]  \right]$$

Putting it into the logic sentence,
$$ = \left[ IU \wedge MM \right] \wedge  \left[ HU \vee [\neg IU \wedge \neg MM ]  \right] \wedge \left[  \neg HU \vee MG \right]$$

The first clause tells us that we definitely need $IU$ so the $[\neg IU \wedge \neg MM ] $ can never be satisfied and we must have $HU$.

Reducing, we now have:
$$ = \left[ IU \wedge MM \right] \wedge  \left[ HU \right] \wedge \left[  \neg HU \vee MG \right]$$

We know that $\neg HU$ can never be true now so we're left with just

$$ \left[ IU \wedge MM \right] \wedge  \left[ HU \right] \wedge \left[ MG \right]$$

So our four clauses are the ones above? Is this correct?

Comment: Is there some kind of conclusion that you need to draw, or is the assignment simply to form clauses out of the given statements?  Also, I would separate those variables, so that you have U for unicorn, M for mammal, etc., because you have some overlap between the different variables, and also because you have some negations you can play with, e.g. Immortal is the negation of mortal. In doing so, a 'mortal mammal' could become a conjunction of mortal and mammal, and Immortal unicorn would become a conjunction of Unicorn and the negation of mortal.

Comment: @Bram28
So the first part of the problem says to form clauses out of them and the instructions mention to only use the given variables(although I agree using single letters is nicer). The second part of the problem tells us to comment if the following statements logically follow $$ \\

\text{the unicorn is mythical}


\\
\text{the unicorn is magical}

\\

\text{the unicorn is horned}$$

Comment: So I guess only the last two statements logically follow if my work above is correct, while the first statement isn't necessarily true(or just False).

Comment: Adopting @Bram28's excellent suggestion, and adopting the notation $PQ:=P\land Q,$ the first half of your answer becomes: YU = “Mythical Unicorn”, IU = “Immortal Unicorn”, RM = “Mortal Mammal”, HU = “Horned Unicorn”, GU = “Magical Unicorn” $$(¬YU∨IU)(IU∨RM)(¬IU∨HU)(¬RM∨HU)(¬HU∨GU)$$ And since the discussion is purely about unicorns, taking out the Mammal and Unicorn simplifies the above to $$(¬Y∨I)\land(I∨R)\land(¬I∨H)\land(¬R∨H)\land(¬H∨G).$$

Comment: @ryang Where did $(IU \vee RM) come from?

Comment: That should read $(IU \vee RM)$

Comment: @bigbear Might have been a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion of $[IU \land MM]$ sounds inconsistent simply by their meaning. Clearly it's easier to use case analysis based on your given propositional premises with the additional tautology $MM \lor \lnot MM$ which you can always adjoin using classic logic. I'll just sketch a proof below and you can convert to a strict proof according to your specific rules.

We have $MM \lor \lnot MM, (IU \lor MM) \to HU \equiv (IU \to HU) \land (MM \to HU), HU \to MG$, so from these when we do a case analysis on $MM$, we can easily derive $HU \land MG$ from detachment rule (MP). Also on the other hand, if we assume $\lnot MM$ with the remaining premises $\lnot MY \to MM \equiv \lnot MM \to MY$ (CP) and $MY \to IU$, then we can easily have $IU \land HU \land MG$.

So in conclusion we can derive the final clause $HU \land MG$ from all your 4 premises without $MY$ though.